# Can skrulls shapeshift into other skrulls?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel, spider-man-far-from-home

I was wondering if Skrulls have the ability to shapeshift themselves into other Skrulls.

Comment: It's Skrulls all the way down

Answer (score 5):

### Why not?

They have the ability to replicate other beings on a DNA level so shifting to another form with almost *identical* DNA would actually be simpler than any other form.

We don't *see* it happen in the MCU but there is no practical reason why they should not have this ability.